# Find the missing value in the given figure

Tags: logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

**Find the missing value value in the given below figure[image]**

**Choose the correct option :

(a) 22

(b) 34

(c) 36**

**Could anyone give me hint to crack the logic in this figure to get the missing value? I tried a lot but didn't get luck.**

[Source](https://unacademy.com/)

Comment: Hi Girish, and welcome to Puzzling :) Where did you find this puzzle, please? All puzzles which originate elsewhere need to have just a short acknowledgement of their source given in the question, so we make sure the original creator is credited. Please could you edit in the source information? Thanks! :)

Comment: @Stiv one of my friend solve the question on Unacademy portal. And he got this puzzle there. I wrote the exact question what was aksed on that. Still I am thinking to figure out the logic behind the missing number

Answer (score 6):

Answer is

> (b) 34

Reasoning

> First figure - 2/1 + 12/2 + 18/3 + 32/4 = 22 (a/1 + b/2 + c/3 + d/4)

> Second figure - 4/1 + 20/2 + 15/3 + 12/4 = 22

> Similarily the answer is - 9/1 + 18/2 +21/3 + 36/4 =34

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and help.

Answer (score 3):

Could the answer simply be

> (a) 22

Reasoning

> Regardless of the numbers on the outside, the middle number is always 22.

Comment: it could be the answer, but a logic should be strong to support our answer

Comment: According to the principle of Occam's razor that is the best answer.  To avoid the confusion 22 should not be among the possible answers.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A010861  :-)